# I am getting a weird error, should I be worried ? The error has weird characters and says "fatal javascript error occured"

Tags: windows-11, window, rootkit

Here is the error below. I accidentally deleted some files so I am just curious if this is a virus.

> [image: Fatal javascript errror]

Comment: Looks like a corrupt Discord installation.

Comment: Turns out I have a rootkit I ran avast1 scan any other advice Not sure if that is related.

Comment: How do you get this error exactly?

Comment: Turns out I have a rootkit I  -------- Use Kaspersky TDSS Killer.   Make the portable USB setup to test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the program you're running can't open files, or can't open `tray.png`. It's not a virus. It looks like discord aswell. Try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally an issue associated with trying to run the communication application discord. If that's what's happening, then it shouldn't be a concern and you'd just do this to fix it.

If you have discord installed then to fix this you would go to C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\discord and delete the associated data in there. You'll have to log back in to discord if you do that, but it should fix the issue. If it doesn't, I would try restarting your desktop. If that still doesn't fix the issue try uninstalling the discord application and reinstalling it. Hope that helps.

If you're still getting this error or don't have discord installed at all, you likely have a bug or virus. I would go into your applications and uninstall anything you don't recognize. Then, run an anti-malware application such as Malwarebytes.